# is there a faster Way to display massive amounts of ascii (with font size and font type) than JTextPane

Tags: java, text, ascii

I have a video to ASCII animation converter and the pre-processing and compiling I do outside is fast but when I start displaying text it lags a lot in the beginning I thought it was that bad to calculate text size but using system.out.prinln was superfast and even if the carriage return works (which it doesn't) I'd like to have a sperate GUI/CLI panel for it

here is sample code that turns an image into ASCII

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    static short width;
    static short height;
    public static BufferedImage mytoBufferedImage(Image img){
        if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
        {
            return (BufferedImage) img;
        }
        BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),
                img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D bGr = buffImage.createGraphics();
        bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        bGr.dispose();

        return buffImage;
    }
    public static BufferedImage scaleApple(BufferedImage image){
        return mytoBufferedImage(
                image.getScaledInstance(width, height, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FontFormatException, InterruptedException {
        width = 256;
        height = 192;

        BufferedImage Frame;

        ArrayList<String> FrameBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder ASCIIFrame;
        ArrayList<Byte> Bright;
        final String[] Rendered;

        byte R;
        byte G;
        byte B;

        Frame = mytoBufferedImage(new ImageIcon("example.jpg").getImage());

        Bright = new ArrayList<>();

        int[] data =((DataBufferInt)
                scaleApple(Frame)
                        .getRaster()
                        .getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        for (int datum : data) {
            Color c = new Color(datum);
            R = (byte) c.getRed();
            G = (byte) c.getGreen();
            B = (byte) c.getBlue();
            Bright.add((byte) Math.round(Math.sqrt( 0.299*((R&0xFF)^2) + 0.587*((G&0xFF)^2) + 0.114*((B&0xFF)^2))));
        }

        ASCIIFrame = new StringBuilder();
        // j+(width*i) is cords
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Main.width; j++) {
                byte bright = Bright.get((j + (width * i)));
                if ((bright <= 16) && (bright >= 12)) {
                    ASCIIFrame.append('█');
                    ASCIIFrame.append('█');
                }else if ((bright <= 12) && (bright >= 8)) {
                    ASCIIFrame.append('▓');
                    ASCIIFrame.append('▓');
                }else if ((bright <= 8) && (bright >= 4)) {
                    ASCIIFrame.append('▒');
                    ASCIIFrame.append('▒');
                }else {
                    ASCIIFrame.append(' ');
                    ASCIIFrame.append(' ');
                }
            }
            ASCIIFrame.append('\n');
        }
        FrameBuffer.add(ASCIIFrame.toString());

        Rendered = FrameBuffer.toArray(String[]::new);


        JTextPane render = new JTextPane();
        render.setDoubleBuffered(false);

        InputStream fontIS = new FileInputStream("JetBrainsMonoNL-Regular.ttf");

        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontIS).deriveFont(3f);
        render.setFont(font);

        StyledDocument doc = render.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);


        JFrame Jframe = new JFrame();

        JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
        MainPanel.add(render);
        render.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

        Jframe.setTitle("Ascii");
        Jframe.setSize(730, 645);
        Jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Jframe.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        Jframe.setContentPane(MainPanel);
        Jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Jframe.setVisible(true);

        for (String Rendered_frame: Rendered){
            System.out.println(Rendered_frame); // FAST
            render.setText(Rendered_frame); // 99%GPU usage on rtx 3060
            Thread.sleep(300);// timer methode in actual code
        }
    }
}
```

I tried carriage return, to make it easy to see System.out.println('\r'+Rendered_frame); and it didn't work

and Making A buffered Image and drawing on it with Graphics2D then displaying it on a Jlabel, is inaccurate, the display flickers and chops even with double Buffered set to true

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by that?

Comment: what happened when you typed the words into your favourite seach machine ;)